# Is there something like maybe_owns_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers

A kind of smart pointer that has a functionality roughly like this:

```
class maybe_owns_ptr {
public:
    maybe_owns_ptr(void* ptr, bool owns)
      : ptr(ptr)
      , owns(owns)
    {}

    ~maybe_owns_ptr()
    {
        if (owns) delete ptr;
    }
private:
    void* ptr;
    bool owns;
};
```

(The class should be templated to include the type of the pointer, and a deletion function, and also other constructors and assignment functions etc, but I omitted that for brevity)

Does a class that can store both pointers that it owns (and will deconstruct) and pointers that it doesn't own (and thus won't deconstruct) or something with similar functionality already exist in `std`? Could I achieve this functionality with other `std` components without having to create a new class myself?

Comment: Why not just `std::shared_ptr`? If it owns and is the last one, it will delete it, if not it won't

Comment: What would you want copying such a pointer to do?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` comes somewhat close. You can pass a no-op deleter to it.

Comment: @tas If I construct a `std::shared_ptr` from a raw pointer, it will own the object and delete it when itself is deleted. I don't see how I could emulate the "doesn't own and won't deconstruct" part of my answer with `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @igor Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!